# factorial of a negative number exceeds maximum call stack size

Tags: javascript, recursion, math, factorial, callstack

Why is the `maximum call stack size exceeded` when attempting to apply this simple factorial function to a negative number?

```
function factorial(n) { 
    if (n == 0) { 
        return 1 
    }

    return n * factorial(n - 1) 
}
```

I understand that factorial functions are meant for non-negative integers, but I'm  wondering what is happening internally/in a JavaScript engine when this function is called on e.g. `-1`.

Comment: Your `if` should test for `n <= 0`. Otherwise how will the recursion ever stop?

Comment: It's trying to calculate `-1 * -2 * -3 * -4 * -5 * -6 * -7 ...` and it runs out of memory because it never stops making nested function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It runs infinetly because (n == 0) doesnt met

if you pass  a negative number

```
return n * factorial(n - 1)
```

invokes factorial function with more negative number recursively and thereby (n == 0) condition  doesn't met